# Anybody knows where to learn AIMA python library?

Tags: python-3.x, logic, artificial-intelligence

I am having an "Introduction to AI" course and we were assigned to do a mini project about a simple expert system using AIMA library in python (from the book AI: Modern Approach). I am having some difficulties in writing FOL knowledge base rules in this library particularly, in class they didn't provide us with enough examples and I am struggling to find any online resources.